# Looking for fastest polygon intersection algorithm when many test polygons can overlap a single test polygon

Tags: polygon, collision-detection, shapes, intersection, overlap

I am working on a polygon collision problem.  The goal of the problem is to determine what percentage of a reference polygon is overlapped by a set of test polygons as quickly as possible.  Here are a few details about the problem:

- The problem is in 2D
- The reference polygon is always convex
- Each test polygon is also convex
- If the union of test polygons is created, then the union can be concave
- There can be many test polygons, but only one reference polygon
- We plan to use this algorithm on large sets (hundreds of thousands to millions) of reference and test polygons.

[image: Minimal problem image]
In the image above I have created a reference polygon in green.  I have also created two test polygons in grey.  The outlined shape in red is the shape I want to calculate.  After calculating the shape in red I can calculate the area of the red shape and divide it by the area of the green shape in order to determine percentage overlap.

My first guess for solving this problem is to create the union of all shapes in grey and then do a concave polygon intersection operation between the combined grey shape and the green shape.  Is there a less naive way of doing this?